# Spam moving to Junk folder whit Dovecot Sieve on 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, server, email

I'm first time here. One small company asked Me to create a e-mail server. Nothing fancy, it should work in email clients like Outlook, iOS, Android. No Web mail is needed.

I have no experience with mail servers so I'm creating most basic one following [this tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu-14-04) with dovecot imap access following in that link (Build a Secure Email Server on Ubuntu Part 4: Postfix, Dovecot and TLS Encryption, sorry I can't post more links). User base is local users as around 10 mail accounts will be needed.

The same site has tutorial for [spam filter](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/block-spam-email-apache-spamassassin-ubuntu-16-04). It is working, spam is marked as spam in inbox, but I need that mail is delivered to Junk folder.

I have searched Google a lot, but I can get it working. I have tried a lot of examples, but there is not much on Google. Far as I know Dovecot Sieve is needed, but how to configure it correctly?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 release.